# Find a word in a text file and replace it with the filename

Tags: awk

I have a lot of text files in which I would like to find the word 'CASE' and replace it with the related filename.
I tried

```
find . -type f | while read file
do
awk '{gsub(/CASE/,print "FILENAME",$0)}' $file >$file.$$
mv $file.$$ >$file
done
```

but I got the following error

> awk: syntax error at source line 1  context is >>> {gsub(/CASE/,print <<<  "CASE",$0)}
>   awk: illegal statement at source line 1

I also tried

```
for i in $(ls *); 
do 
awk '{gsub(/CASE/,${i},$0)}' ${i} > file.txt; 
done
```

getting an empty output and

> awk: syntax error at source line 1  context is >>> {gsub(/CASE/,${ <<<
>   awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: Never do `for i in $(ls *)` as that adds nothing compared to `for i in *` and introduces possible error cases like files with spaces in their names. Also, awk is not shell - you cannot access a shell variable inside an awk script, just like you cannot access a shell variable inside a C program. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to pass the VALUE of a shell variable to an awk script.

Answer (score 2):

Why `awk`? `sed` is what you want:

```
while read -r file; do 
    sed -i "s/CASE/${file##*/}/g" "$file"
done < <( find . -type f )
```

or

```
while read -r file; do 
    sed -i.bak "s/CASE/${file##*/}/g" "$file"
done < <( find . -type f )
```

To create a backup of the original.

Comment: I'd probably fix the output from find rather than the variable expansion but <shrug>.

Comment: I'm sure you would like to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/171318) :)

Comment: @EdMorton, no you did it, you left me scratching my head? The read command is reading filenames, not the file itself and I can't see that requiring altering `IFS` to prevent stripping leading/trailing whitespace. The `sed` command will preserve the whitespace. Where is it you see stripping occurring?

Comment: That's ok, I still have a bit of hair left, so scratching my head does no harm. It certainly helps me think back through the problem more closely `:p`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post any sample input and expected output so this is a guess but maybe this is what you want:

```
find . -type f |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    awk '{gsub(/CASE/,FILENAME)} 1' "$file" > "${file}.$$" &&
    mv "${file}.$$" "$file"
done
```

Every change I made to the shell code is important so if you don't understand why I changed any part of it, ask the question.

btw if after making the changes you are still getting the error message:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

then you are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Never use that awk. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or nawk if you must).

Caveats: the above will fail if your file name contains newlines or ampersands (`&`) or escaped digits (e.g. `\1`). See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for details. If any of that is a problem, post some representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: I'm sure you would like to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/171318) :)

Answer (score 1):

`print` in that first script is the error.

The second argument to `gsub` is the replacement string not a command.

You want just `FILENAME`. (Note not `"FILENAME"` that's a literal string. `FILENAME` the variable.)

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file
do
    awk '{gsub(/CASE/,FILENAME,$0)} 7' "$file" >"$file.$$"
    mv "$file.$$" "$file"
done
```

Note that I quoted all your variables and fixed your `find | read` pipeline to work correctly for files with odd characters in the names (see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more about that). I also fixed the erroneous `>` in the `mv` command.

See the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/171318) for how to properly escape the original filename to make it safe to use in the replacement portion of `gsub`.

Also note that recent (4.1+ I believe) versions of awk have the `-i inplace` argument.

To fix the second script you need to add the quotes you removed from the first script.

```
for i in *; do awk '{gsub(/CASE/,"'"${i}"'",$0)}' "${i}" > file.txt; done
```

Note that I got rid of the worse than useless use of `ls` (worse than useless because it actively breaks files with spaces or shell metacharacters in the their names (see [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more on that).

That command though is somewhat ugly and unsafe for filenames with various characters in them and would be better written as the following though:

```
for i in *; do awk -v fname="$i" '{gsub(/CASE/,fname,$0)}' "${i}" > file.txt; done
```

since that will work with filenames with double quotes/etc. in their names correctly whereas the direct variable expansion version will not.

That being said the corrected first script is the right answer.

Comment: `/CASE/,"${i}",$0` wouldn't work as you'd get the literal string `${i}`. You'd instead need something like `/CASE/,"'"$i"'",$0` but I wouldn't do it as it's still open to insidious breakage. Also, `$0` is the default 3rd arg for `*sub()` so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: @EdMorton Point. I'd assumed double quotes there. Fixing.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm sure you would like to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/171318) :) (Sorry, for posting it three times. I just wanted to be fair)

Comment: @hek2mgl Indeed. I favorited that question when it was happening so I'd have it for reference but didn't think about it here.

Comment: Don't worry, I've added that just for fun! :) Who minds that when typing a command? ... For a shell application/framework it might be good to have (at)mkelement's answer it mind and create a function like (at)EdMorton suggested there. (and using it, of course)